# service mysql restart with default options

Tags: mysql, options

I have Ubuntu 14.04 with MariaDB Galera cluster installed. 
My cluster has just one node now, so I restart the mysql service using: 
`sudo service mysql restart --wsrep-new-cluster`
How can I set this option to be added automatically when a program restarts the mysql service?
In example, I need this when I install a new PHP module, because PHP tries to restart automatically mysql service but it doesn't work without the `--wsrep-new-cluster` option.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the way to achieve my goal:

1. Edit `my.cnf` file (it is usually located in `/etc/mysql/`).
2. Locate `[mysqld]` group ("Basic Settings").
3. Write `wsrep-new-cluster` inside [mysqld] group (I added it under `skip-external-locking` option).
4. Save my.cnf file and exit.
5. Try `sudo service mysql restart` from terminal. This should work without add more options.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html